# Can two substrings be combined to one?

Tags: javascript

In Google's diff_match_patch I found the following code:

```
best_common = shorttext.substring(j - suffixLength, j) +
            shorttext.substring(j, j + prefixLength);
```

But isn't this the same as:

```
best_common = shorttext.substring(j - suffixLength, j + prefixLength);
```

?

If you want to see this code in it's natural habitat, please look at the source:

https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/source/browse/trunk/javascript/diff_match_patch_uncompressed.js

Look for line 673 and 674.

Comment: yes, some people just do things the long way

Comment: This should be the same

Comment: Quite, it's only different when `suffixLength` or `prefixLength` are negative.

Comment: Could you link the source for some context please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they would be the same as `suffixLength` and `prefixLength` are guaranteed to be non-negative in your case.

Answer (score 1):

These are equivalent for most cases. However, there is an edge case to consider.

For the following sample, let's suppose that `shorttext == "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`.

## `prefixLength` or `suffixLength` is negative

Let `j = 12`, `prefixLength = -4` and `suffixLength = -5`. Then

```
shorttext.substring(j - suffixLength, j) + shorttext.substring(j, j + prefixLength)
// == "mnopq" + "jkl"
shorttext.substring(j - suffixLength, j + prefixLength)
// == "jklmnopq"
```